# Unable to reference object attributes

Tags: java, arrays, object, attributes

First question on Stack Overflow!
I feel like this *has* to be a common question amongst Java beginners. But I've been trying for hours and have been unable to discover the solution. I *thought* that object attributes *could* be accessed this way.

At first I thought that `weapon[0]` was, in fact, an object array, so when I created object array `Inventory[] inventory`, I was using an object array in the constructor. I immediately fixed that, but this issue still persists.

It's even more annoying because, in debug mode, I can *literally see* `weapon[0]` inside of `Inventory[] inventory` with its attributes.
[Look at Eclipse mock me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRjVH.png)

My current theory is that placing object `weapon[0]`, instance of class `Weapons`, in the object array `Inventory[] inventory` may be the issue, and that the object's attributes aren't accessible somehow because of that placement. Any help would be appreciated, thanks! And this is my first time messing with arrays, so I am definitely a novice. Any tips about my formatting and such would also be very helpful!

```
package arraytest;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;

public class ArrayTest {
    
    static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    static int i = 0;
    static int choice = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Weapons[] weapon = new Weapons[3];
        weapon[0] = new Weapons(0,"Wooden Sword",1,2);
        weapon[1] = new Weapons(1,"Bronze Sword",2.5,7.5);
        weapon[2] = new Weapons(2,"Iron Sword",5,10);
        
        Armor[] armor = new Armor[3];
        armor[0] = new Armor(3,"Wooden Armor",2,5);
        armor[1] = new Armor(4,"Bronze Armor",3,10);
        armor[2] = new Armor(5,"Iron Armor",5,15);
        
        Enemy[] enemy = new Enemy[3];
        enemy[0] = new Enemy(0,"Skeleton",3,0,10);
        enemy[1] = new Enemy(1,"Goblin",2,1,5);
        enemy[2] = new Enemy(2,"Zombie",4,1,8);
        
        Inventory[] inventory = new Inventory[256];
        
        String chooseweapon = String.format(
                "Choose your weapon:\n"
                + "1. %s\n"
                + "2. %s\n"
                + "3. %s\n"
                ,
                weapon[0].name,
                weapon[1].name,
                weapon[2].name
                );
        System.out.print(chooseweapon);
        
        while (i==0) {
            i++; //1
            
            try {
                choice = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Error. Try again.");
                i--; //0
                continue;
            }
            if (choice < 1 || choice > 3) {
                System.out.println("Error. Try again.");
                i--; //0
            }
        }
        if (choice == 1) {
            inventory[0] = new Inventory(weapon[0]);
        }
        System.out.println(inventory[0].item); //this is the problem here. i can't put .item.name, error is "name cannot be resolved or is not a field"
    }
}



class Inventory {
    
    public Object item;
    Inventory(Object item) {
        this.item = item;
        
    }
}

class Armor {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public double defnum;
    public double val;
    
    Armor(int id, String name, double defnum, double val) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.defnum = defnum;
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class Weapons {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public double attdmg;
    public double val;
    
    Weapons(int id, String name, double attdmg, double val) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.attdmg = attdmg;
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class Enemy {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public double attdmg;
    public double defnum;
    public double health;
    
    Enemy(int id, String name, double attdmg, double defnum, double health) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.attdmg = attdmg;
        this.defnum = defnum;
        this.health = health;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your instance variable `item` is of type `Object`, and that type simply doesn't have a `name` field. So you either can specialize the type or cast the expression `inventory[0].item` to a `Weapon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a well-worded question!

This has to do with the difference between the types at runtime vs. the types at compile time. You declared `item` to be of type `Object`.

Java allows for *polymorphism*, which, when you declare the `item` in `Inventory` to be type `Object`, allows you to assign anything to `item` which "is-a" `Object` (so that means you can assign a `String`, an `Integer`, any object to `item`, since those all inherit from the `Object` class).

However, when you go to access `item` later on in the program, Java can't *guarantee* at compile-time that whatever `item` references has a `name` property! `Integer`, for example, *is an* `Object`, but *does not* have a `name` property! The Java compiler just says, "all I know is that `item` is an `Object`, and I won't let you access a property not all `Object`s have!".

When you run the program, however, the *runtime*-type of `item` is `Weapon`, so Eclipse is able to show you its properties. But Java is designed to catch as many errors as possible at compile-time, so it will not allow you to access the `name` property if it can't guarantee at compile-time that it has a name.

This may seem annoying or unnecessarily restrictive (you *know* everything *you* are going to put in `Inventory` will have a name!), so this is the point of superclasses & interfaces! These features allow you the flexibility to create different types of objects that all share similar properties or methods, *and* still allows Java to catch all these potential issues upfront.

To fix this, you can create an `InventoryItem` superclass that both `Armor` and `Weapon` extend, that has a `name` property. You can then declare `item` to be of type `InventoryItem`. That way, Java will know that, even though the *runtime-type* may be either a `Weapon` or `Armor`, it's *guaranteed* to have a name.

We can introduce a new class, such as `InventoryItem`:

```java
class Inventory {

    public InventoryItem item;
    public int id;

    Inventory(InventoryItem item, int id) {
        this.item = item;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And then class `Inventory` can take an `InventoryItem` (I suggest probably the inventory to contain the array of items)

```java
class Inventory {

    public InventoryItem item;

    Inventory(InventoryItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
```

And then your classes, such as `Armor`, can extend `InventoryItem`, for example:

```java
class Armor extends InventoryItem {

    public double defnum;
    public double val;

    Armor(int id, String name, double defnum, double val) {
        super(name, id);
        this.defnum = defnum;
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

And then this will work!

```
System.out.println(inventory[0].item.name); //Java now knows that inventory[0] is type Inventory, its "item" property is type InventoryItem, and that is *guaranteed* to have a name and id!
```

Comment: As the subclasses also have the `id` field in common, it might make sense to put that also into the superclass.

Comment: Good point @Seelenvirtuose, edited.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It works fairly well, although it is quite annoying that the superclass `InventoryItem` needs to have all of the arguments/attributes of the classes that extend it present for those attributes to then be called later. I was trying to avoid such tedium, as I had a hunch that this was the solution, but it was much simpler than I thought.

Comment: @GiavonniPapenbrock you’re welcome! You *could*, in theory, cast to a Weapon type when you access the element if you know that the object will always be a Weapon, but this is poor design, as if it happens to not be a weapon, it will fail with a ClassCastException at runtime. What you’re probably looking for is called “duck typing” and Java simply doesn’t support it (besides reflection, which I also don’t recommend here). A dynamically typed language such as JS or Python gives you this flexibility, with the tradeoff of not being able to guarantee certain crashes won’t happen at runtime.

Comment: @Giogification one thing I should mention: a language like Scala allows you to do, I believe, exactly what you’d be looking for through *structural typing*, where you can essentially declare that an object must have this name property, and any type that does have the property is acceptable. E.g. https://devopedia.org/images/article/24/7477.1514520259.jpg